# vnsprintf() caused the segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault

```
Core was generated by `MNM_SVR'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
    #0  0x00002b9aa9c548e2 in __strlen_sse2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    (gdb) where
    #0  0x00002b9aa9c548e2 in __strlen_sse2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #1  0x00002b9aa9c1ce2d in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #2  0x00002b9aa9c43c8b in vsnprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #3  0x00002b9aa8e3b941 in fill_errinfo (log_flag=1, line=345, function=0x2b9aa8e50410 "InMNMThread", file=0x2b9aa8e50327 "mnm.c", 
        fmt=0x2b9aa8e50888 "invoke failed!service[%s],errno[%d],desc[%s]") at error_trace_th.c:309
    #4  0x00002b9aa8e42e21 in InMNMThread (p=0x2b9aa9069b40) at mnm.c:345
    #5  0x00002b9aa99be806 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
    #6  0x00002b9aa9caf59d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: va_start(argptr, fmt); 
    ret = vsnprintf(err_str, MAX_DATA_LEN, fmt, argptr);  /* this is line 309*/
    va_end(argptr);

Answer (score 0):

There's nowhere *near* enough information in this question to be certain<sup>(1)</sup> but, generally, segmentation violations in `strlen`-type calls is almost always caused by non-terminated strings.

I suggest you look there, possibly your format string itself but most likely the string variables for the service name or description, as per:

```
"invoke failed!service[%s],errno[%d],desc[%s]"
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Some code, or even an actual *question,* probably would have been a good idea :-)